# How to generate a feature value distribution plot for a data set using?

Tags: r, visualization

I am interested in generating the following plots for one of the existing data set. However, I could not find which functionalities in R can help me to do that.  I tried the plot function in kohonen package, but there is no option for generating those kind of plots.

[image]

Comment: Try package [hexbin](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/hexbin/index.html).

Comment: @Justin, could you add this as an answer? I could do it, but you commented first :).

Answer (score 3):

I find the syntax of the `ggplot2` to be the most pleasant for most of my plotting needs.  In this case, you want `geom_hex` or `stat_hexbin`.

From the [ggplot2 documentation](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/stat_binhex.html)

```
d <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(carat, price))
d + stat_binhex()
```

---

As per comment, if you don't want binning you can still use `geom_hex` with `stat='identity'` I think.  Or, you can use `geom_tile` to do this, but then you will not have pretty hexagons...

Comment: thanks for the answer. But it is a bit different with what I am thinking of, that is, each cell in the plot should correspond to one data point. Its values is illustrated through the color. The color-value correspondence is reflected in the right bar along the plot.

Comment: @user785099 Feel free to read the rest of the `ggplot2` documentation... you want `geom_tile`.  If you still cannot figure it out on your own, please post a complete example as another question with data and what you have tried and you will find you get much better help.  As it stands now, there is no way anyone can guess exactly what you're starting with, what you have looked into and what hasn't worked...